# logstash pattern to grep tomcat access logs

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I have a tomcat access log as below

```
122.164.121.231 - - [23/Nov/2015:07:19:54 -0500] "GET /configs/config/loggedinuser@gmail.com HTTP/1.1" 200 1135
```

And I have written a logstash pattern which works fine and picks the data

```
%{IP:clientip} \- \- \[%{NOTSPACE:date} \-%{INT}\] \"%{WORD:action} /%{WORD}/%{WORD}/%{NOTSPACE:login} %{WORD:protocol}/%{NUMBER:protocolNum}\" %{NUMBER:status} %{NUMBER}
```

But This pattern works only when the API url is constant i.e.

```
/configs/config/loggedinuser@gmail.com
```

as it is in the pattern

```
/%{WORD}/%{WORD}/%{NOTSPACE:login}
```

In my case i want to get the whole API independent of the pattern e.g. /configs/config/loggedinuser@gmail.com or

How would i be able to do that?

Edit:

Found that using %{GREEDYDATA:api} i am able to get the complete API string

Comment: What do you mean by `/configs/config/thecelloserenades@gmail.com or`? You mean the API url could change?

Comment: Yes I meant that API URL can change and is not constant.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for multiple levels of "/"? Then yea you could do

`%{IP:clientip} \- \- \[%{NOTSPACE:date} \-%{INT}\] \"%{WORD:action} /%{GREEDYDATA:api} %{WORD:protocol}/%{NUMBER:protocolNum}\" %{NUMBER:status} %{NUMBER}`

Was there something else?

There is a pretty cool debugger for the Grok filter plugin for logstash http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

Also, we are working on an API debugging tool which may be helpful, but full disclosure since I am the CEO. https://www.moesif.com/features